# Python: calculating subtraction of columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is like this:

```
   id_A  id_B  f1_A  f2_A  f3_A  f1_B  f2_B  f3_B  t
      1     2     1     2     3     4     5     6  1
      2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9  0
      3     4     7     8     9     8     7     6  1
```

I want to do a subtraction to produce results like this:

```
   id_A  id_B  f1_A-f1_B  f2_A-f2_B  f3_A-f3_B  t
      1     2    -3          -3         -3      1
      2     3    -3          -3         -3      0
      3     4    -1           1          3      1
```

Which is, (the 3rd to the 5th column in the df) substract (the 6th to the 8th column in the df), while changing the index of the columns to be fx_A-fy_A.

I tried using

```
df[cols[2:5]].sub(df[cols[5:8]], fill_value=0)
```

However, the result is definately not what I wanted:

```
   f1_A  f1_B  f2_A  f2_B  f3_A  f3_B
    1.0  -4.0   2.0  -5.0   3.0  -6.0
    4.0  -7.0   5.0  -8.0   6.0  -9.0
    7.0  -8.0   8.0  -7.0   9.0  -6.0
```

I have no idea right now as to how to achieve the desired results. Sorry for my English, I'm still a beginner in Python, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) columns based on whether they end in `_A` or `_B`, then do your calculation on those filtered dataframes. Put all other columns in your index, and then reset the index at the end to get them back:

```
df.set_index(['id_A','id_B','t'],inplace=True)

A = df.filter(regex='f*_A')
B = df.filter(regex='f*_B')

new_df = (A.values - B)

# Join your column names
new_df.columns = ['-'.join((x,y)) for x,y in zip(A.columns,B.columns)]

new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>> new_df
   id_A  id_B  t  f1_A-f1_B  f2_A-f2_B  f3_A-f3_B
0     1     2  1         -3         -3         -3
1     2     3  0         -3         -3         -3
2     3     4  1         -1          1          3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['f1_A-f1_B'] = df['f1_A'] - df['f1_B']
df['f2_A-f2_B'] = df['f2_A'] - df['f2_B']
df['f3_A-f3_B'] = df['f3_A'] - df['f3_B']
print(df[['id_A', 'id_B', 'f1_A-f1_B', 'f2_A-f2_B', 'f3_A-f3_B', 't']])
#    id_A  id_B  f1_A-f1_B  f2_A-f2_B  f3_A-f3_B  t
# 0     1     2    -3          -3         -3      1
# 1     2     3    -3          -3         -3      0
# 2     3     4    -1           1          3      1
```